# UNIX shell: how do you tail up to a searchable expression?

Tags: shell, text-processing, unix

The end of git status looks like this:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Classes/Default.png
#       Classes/Default@2x.png
...
```

Since you might have any number of untracked files, I'm trying to tail from the end of the file to "Untracked files" and save it to a temp file, strip out the first three lines and convert the filenames to git add Classes/...

I can't seem to find a good way (other than maybe a different language) to tail up to a searchable expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tail command:

```
tail -$(($(wc -l < file.txt) - $(grep -n "Untracked files" file.txt|cut -d: -f1) - 2)) file.txt
```

How it works:
total number of lines in file = `wc -l < file.txt`
line number of "Untracked files" = `grep -n "Untracked files" file.txt|cut -d: -f1`
The `-2` is to remove the top lines

Complete command with `git add`:

```
tail -$(($(wc -l < file.txt) - $(grep -n "Untracked files" file.txt|cut -d: -f1) - 2)) file.txt | tr -d '#'| while read line; do echo git add $line; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed` to print everything from "Untracked files" to the end:

```
git status | sed -n '/Untracked files:$/,$p'
```

Then you just have to parse the filenames by removing the `#` character.

You can also use `git status -s` to get a shorter, more easily parsed output:

```
~$ git status -s
?? Classes/Default.png
?? Classes/Default@2x.png
```

This is a good application of `awk`, which lets you grep and extract at the same time:

```
~$ git status -s | awk '/\?\?/{print $2}'
Classes/Default.png
Classes/Default@2x.png
```

Alternatively: `awk '{if ($1 == "??") print $2}'`

You can also, of course, use `git add` to list (and add) untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to:

```
perl -e 'my ($o, $p) = (0, shift); while(<>){print if $o or $o = /$p/}' "$MY_REGEX"
```

Where `$MY_REGEX` is your pattern. In your case, probably `'^\s{7}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using shell scripting.

First start reading the file in a while loop, keep a count of the number of lines read, break the loop when the required line is found. 
Using the count of lines tail the file and then extract file names using awk.

```
i=0; 
l=`wc -l filename | awk '{print $1}'`; 

while read line; 
do i=`echo $i + 1 | bc`; 
if [[ $line == "# Untracked files:" ]]; 
then break; 
fi; 
done < "filename"; 

tail -`echo $l -$i -2 | bc` filename | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```

Here "filename" is the file you want to process

Comment: you don't need to read the file yourself. Use `grep -n`. You don't need `bc` either. See my answer.

Comment: @fahd: Yes. Your solution is simpler.

Comment: Sorry Athena, it was my first time posting, I didn't even realize what you meant until I researched and for some reason I didn't see your request until now...